# Turn.js & AJAX Integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, turn.js

I have been working on turn.js but didn't find any example regarding loading dynamic pages with content via ajax, the page is loading, but not with all result
[json result from controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds7aF.jpg)

```
<div class="sample-flipbook" id="BookViewer">
            <div id="book-js" class="text-center">
                <div class="hard">
                    <img src="~/Theme/OtherAssets/Images/temp-img.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="width:100%; height:100%">
                </div>
                <div class="hard"></div>
                <div id="Page-Loader"></div>
                <div class="hard"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $('#book-js').turn({
            width: 900,
            height: 600,
            autoCenter: true
        });
    });
    function LoadBook(HBID, ChapterNo, TableRef) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Books")',
            type: "GET",
            data: { HadithBookID: HBID, ChapterNo: ChapterNo, TableRefNo: TableRef },
            success: (response) => {

                console.log(response.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    var Html = "<div>";
                    Html += '<p class="urdu-font-fm container-fluid mt-3">' + response[i].ArabicText+'</p>';
                    Html += '<p class="container-fluid">' + (response[i].EnglishText != null ? response[i].EnglishText == null : "") + '</p>';
                    Html += '<p class="urdu-font-fm container-fluid">' + response[i].UrduText+'</p>';
                    Html += '<p class="urdu-font-fm container-fluid">' + (response[i].Language1  != null ? response[i].Language1  == null : "") + '</p>';
                    Html += "</div>";

                    $('#Page-Loader').html(Html);
                }
            },
            error: (response) => { console.log(response); }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: $('#Page-Loader').html(Html); is this line not working?

Comment: This Line is working, & Load only 1 array element on the page, but I need page for each array result

Comment: I have changed the code, now it's showing all the pages, but Over write the first page, and last 2 cover pages.

Comment: not understand overwriting the first page and last page?

Comment: Sorry for miscommunication, the Cover page is all right on first look, but after binding pages from js, cover pages has been removed by the .turn('addPage')

Comment: can you add an image or demo HTML so it's easy to understand what's the exact issue you face.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change

```
$('#Page-Loader').html(Html);
```

this line to

```
$('#Page-Loader').append(Html);
```

if using it inside the loop for getting all html in output result. Now happing is that your previous html replaced with a new html after each loop completing.